# NumPy Weighted Average Error regarding length of weights

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a 1d array of weights with length (6398) and a dataframe with 6398 rows. I am trying to calculate weighted averages for each row to put into a new column in the dataframe. However I'm getting this error message:

```
ValueError: Length of weights not compatible with specified axis.
```

Which doesn't meake sense since it seems like the rows/columns are matching. This is the code for reference:

```
Tdfp1['pbs_monitor_public'] = np.average(arr, axis=1, weights=w)
```

I thought I would have a new column at the end of my data frame with the same number of rows as the rest of it with weighted averages.

Comment: If python tells you it's not matching, chances are python is correct, not you. Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, you can see that the dimension of Weight should match the dimension of the axis where the average is calculated or should be the same dimension as the input matrix.

> [weights](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.average.html#numpy-average) : array_like, optional
> An array of weights associated with the values in a. Each value in a contributes to the average according to its associated weight. The weights array can either be 1-D (in which case its length must be the size of a along the given axis) or of the same shape as a. If weights=None, then all data in a are assumed to have a weight equal to one. The 1-D calculation is:
> avg = sum(a * weights) / sum(weights)

So I assume the issue is with the dimension of your weight 'w'. Below is a sample I tried and worked for me.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[10,11,12,13,14,15]])
arr_shape = arr.shape[1] # just to get the shape for creating Weight array.
w=5 # Sample value as weight , this you can changed according to your logic.
w_array = np.array([w]*arr_shape) # weight array created.
print("Input array shape:" , arr.shape)
print("Weight array shape:" ,w_array.shape)
avg = np.average(arr, axis=1, weights=w_array)
print("Average : " , avg)
```

- output

```
Input array shape: (1, 6)
Weight array shape: (6,)
Average :  [12.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you are trying to calculate the weighted average of some number of columns to create a new column. I have build a sample dataframe like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 6398
Tdfp1 = pd.DataFrame({f'c{i}': np.random.rand(N) for i in range(3)})
```

Now, let's specify the columns and their associated weights. Note that the important thing is that there are as many weights as columns.

```py
columns = ['c0', 'c1', 'c2']
w = [1, 2, 3]

assert(len(columns) == len(w))
```

I assume you are working with the columns in `arr` this way:

```py
arr = Tdfp1[columns].values
```

Now, the dimensions make sense, so this works correctly:

```py
Tdfp1['pbs_monitor_public'] = np.average(arr, axis=1, weights=w)
```